# Loguru logger.error writes errors to every log file how to make it write only to error file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, loguru

I have recently started using Python `Loguru` so in order to better understand the library I have created a couple of tests, here's one:

```
from loguru import logger
import random
loggerEven = logger
loggerEven.add("Even.txt", mode='w', level="INFO")

loggerUneven = logger
loggerUneven.add("UnEven.txt", mode='w', level="ERROR")

x = random.randint(0, 11)
print(x)
if x%2 == 1:
    loggerUneven.error("Uneven")
else:
    loggerEven.info("Even")
```

So, if the number is even - all is well. However, when I get an uneven number, the log is written both to `Even.txt` and `UnEven.txt` files. I tried changing `loggerUneven.error` to `loggerUneven.info` and to `loggerUneven.success`, though in the latter cases the logs are written to `Even.txt`, is there any way to make files `Uneven/error` files to be written only to the corresponding file not to every log files?

I have recently started using Python `Loguru` so in order to better understand the library I have created a couple of tests, here's one:

```
from loguru import logger
import random
loggerEven = logger
loggerEven.add("Even.txt", mode='w', level="INFO")

loggerUneven = logger
loggerUneven.add("UnEven.txt", mode='w', level="ERROR")

x = random.randint(0, 11)
print(x)
if x%2 == 1:
    loggerUneven.error("Uneven")
else:
    loggerEven.info("Even")
```

So, if the number is even - all is well. However, when I get an uneven number, the log is written both to `Even.txt` and `UnEven.txt` files. I tried changing `loggerUneven.error` to `loggerUneven.info` and to `loggerUneven.success`, though in the latter cases the logs are written to `Even.txt`, is there any way to make files `Uneven/error` files to be written only to the corresponding file not to every log files?

Comment: You seem to have pasted your question twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loguru` loggers don't work quite how you think. Your `loggerEven` and `loggerUneven` are both actually the same logger object. So you've added two file sinks to the same logger! This is why you're seeing duplicates.

You can verify this with:

```
print(loggerEven is loggerUneven)
```

This will print `True`, demonstrating that they are both the same logger.

However, although you've added two sinks to the same logger, you've added them with different `level` arguments. This is why your `.error(..)` call goes to both files, but your `.info(..)` call goes to both.

You should look at the `filter` argument to `.add(..)`.

The `loguru` docs are excellent and have an example of exactly what you're trying to achieve:

https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources/recipes.html#creating-independent-loggers-with-separate-set-of-handlers